# Compression of a positive DNF

Tags: prolog, boolean-logic, conjunctive-normal-form

I would like to compress **positive** propositional formulas in 
disjunctive normal form (DNF).

I am only assuming simple DNF for the moment without negated 
literals. The reverse process, the decompression can be easily 
defined. For a formula only built from conjunction and disjunction, 
the following rewriting rules will generate a DNF:

```
A & (B v C) --> (A & B) v (A & C)
(A v B) & C --> (A & C) v (B & C)
```

Here is an example of a decompression:

```
Example: Decompression
Input:
  (p & (q v r) & s & (t v u)) v
  w.

Output:
  (p & q & s & t) v
  (p & r & s & t) v
  (p & q & s & u) v
  (p & r & s & u) v
  w.
```

Now I wonder whether there are some algorithms around
which can generate a single formula back from a DNF.
I have already looked into binary decision diagrams. The
problem I have with these is that they cannot combine
all disjunctions on the way.

For example the algorithms for binary decision diagrams that 
use sharing, would still show similar branches during 
printing and/or introduce new prepositional variables, 
both things are not desired:

```
Example: Compression (Bad)
Input:
  (p & q & s & t) v
  (p & r & s & t) v
  (p & q & s & u) v
  (p & r & s & u) v 
  w.

Output:
  (p & ((q & s & (t v u)) v (r & s & (t v u)))) v
  w.

- or -

Output:
  (p & ((q & h) v (r & h))) & (h <-> s & (t v u))) v
  w.
```

The result should be a single formula, **not anymore DNF**,
which is more compact than the binary decision diagram 
algorithms which uses only disjunction and conjunction, 
and the prepositional variables already found in the 
original DNF. Here is an example of the desired compression:

```
Example: Compression (Good)
Input:
  (p & q & s & t) v
  (p & r & s & t) v
  (p & q & s & u) v
  (p & r & s & u) v
  w.

Output:
  (p & (q v r) & s & (t v u)) v
  w.
```

What would be your take? Prolog implementations preferred.

Bye

Comment: This problem is known as [multi-level logic optimization](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-0817-5_2). It is a form of factorization.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a systematic algorithm to compute the minimum of a boolean expression in two layers (either a disjunction of conjunctions of the input variables, or a conjunction of disjunctions of the input variables).

The usual algorithms used to do this are the [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and the [Quine-McCluskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) algorithms.

These algorithms do work with negated variables. In any case, at least if your input is in disjunctive normal form (DNF) and no negated variables appear, the output expressed as disjunction of conjunction of the input variables won't have negated variables either).

Comment: Sounds interesting. What do you mean by two levels? I am not restricting the result to be one simple alternation of & and v, it could also go deeper.

Comment: Also not sure whether Quine–McCluskey solves my problem, since it uses the notation A', which denotes a negative literal. But I will not have any negative literals, so main problem is not applying A v A' = 1, or something in this direction.

Comment: For the question you can already assume a miminal DNF as Input! Then seek as Output something which is neither DNF nor CNF, but smaller. This is the posed problem.

Comment: Yes, thats what Karnaugh or Quine-McCluskey will give. If your input does not have negated logic, the output won't either.

Comment: But I need an algorithm which further massages the DNF. The question is not to minimize the DNF. But to turn it in a smaller non-DNF.

Comment: Sorry, in my comment (removed) i stated that these algorithms will yield DNF/CNF, but I really meant that they yield minimum expressions that are conjunction of disjunctions or disjunctions of conjuntions, and that was what you showed as expected output in your example.

Comment: Right also without negation, some simplifications are possible, for example A v (A & B) = A. But the main simplification I am interested in is the reverse of the decompression rewriting rules: (A & B) v (A & C) --> A & (B v C), (A & C) v (B & C) --> (A v B) & C. Not sure where to start to implement that.

Comment: Example is now disjunction of conjunction of disjunction. But I guess result can go arbitrarily deep, similar like binary decision diagrams (BDD) go arbitrary deep in the alternation of conjunction and disjunction. But Quine-McCluskey is an intersting lead, since I have already thought about operating with the lenght of the input conjunctions.

Comment: This answer is about two-level logic minimization.